# jquery width() is incorrect when scrollbars are not present

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jQuery 3.3.1 and it seems the `width()` function subtracts the width of the scrollbar from the actual width of the element even when scrollbars are not present. According to chrome dev tools, the element is 1128.37px wide but jquery returns its width as 1111.38px. 17px is the width of the scrollbar.

This issue resolves as I increase the length of the page so that scrollbars appear, then the css width gets reduced to 1111.38 too. I've tried every solution in other similar anwers and none of them work.

This seems related to [this issue on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3589) but doesn't look like there was a solution.

So how do I know if I have scrollbars or not? How do I get the width of the element consistently?

Comment: Try [`.clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)

Comment: No I tried this and `getBoundingClientRect()`. Both return 1111px.

Comment: Can't really tell what you should really get because your question doesn't have any code. Read on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried .outerWidth() ?

Comment: @ErwinSanders I have. THis is weird, I [uploaded it on the server](http://bwdmedia.in/slider/) and its calculating fine on it while on the localhost it isnt. The code is obviously the same. Reduce your browser width and reload to remove the scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like below,

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0).scrollWidth > this.width();
    }
})(jQuery);

$('#my_div1').hasScrollBar(); // returns true if there's a `Horizontal` scrollbar, false otherwise..
```

you can get element width consistently like this,

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var winwid = $('#my_div1').width();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.innerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/) and make sure that the element has [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). Tested on jQuery 3.3.1 with Chrome and Firefox.

### Demo

**There are two buttons: first button toggles the scrollbar, second button toggles `box-sizing: border-box` style.**

```js
$('.btn1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('h s');
  $('.box').toggleClass('hidden scroll');
  $('.out').val($('.box').innerWidth() + "px");
});

$('.btn2').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('on off');
  $('.box').toggleClass('border');
  $('.out').val($('.box').innerWidth() + "px");
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000
}
.off::after {content: " off"}
.on::after {content: " on"}
.h::before {content: 'no scrollbar';}
.s::before {content: 'scrollbar';}
.hidden {overflow: hidden;}
.scroll {overflow: scroll;}
.border {box-sizing: border-box}
```

```html
<button class='btn1 h'></button>
<button class='btn2 off'>border-box</button>
<output class='out'></output>
<div class="box hidden"></div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```